# Set shell command as Visual Studio Code include paths source

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've written own Python based build system for my AVR project. Some of the defines and include paths are in dependence of current target  (I build binaries to some MCUs and crystal frequencies). I want to set IntelliSense paths dependent of script stdout output. Is this possible or is there any extension to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python extension for VS Code has various ways to [set extra paths](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense). As for dynamically setting it, you would need to write some code to dynamically update your `settings.json` file.